# Change view sizes inside UIScrollView using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a 3x3 menu, based on a grid of buttons, and I'm facing a lot of problems trying to adapt it to different screen sizes.

Since I want my menu to be equally spaced on the screen (using autolayout tricks on the [Storyboard](http://effortlesscode.com/evenly-spacing-views-auto-layout/)), I have created a custom class with this menu that i'm adding to the center part of the main controller view. The problem is that the menu doesn't fit in small screen (3,5" screens).

Trying to solve this problem, I have created a scrollView in the main screen to add the menu and be able to scroll in small screens.

The problem is that since the view I'm loading in the scrollview, automatically fits to the size of the container (in this case the UIScrollView), only a small part of the menu is appearing in the 3,5" screen, without the option of scrolling (In bigger views it appears equally spaced and everything appears correctly).

How can I solve this UIScrollView problem? Or there is a better solution for this problem?

p.s: I'm sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to add images :(

Comment: I think it's more of a problem of the constraints that you have set. If you have correctly added the constraints of the inner elements, the scroll view will calculate all of it's inner views dimension and adjust its size to enable or disable scrolling. Check all of your inner views constraints. Make sure you have no issues displaying in xcode storyboard and again in console after you launch your app.

Comment: I made the constraints correctly, but I didn't setup correctly the content size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uiscrollview with autolayout has some pain into it.
You need to place you're inner views so the scrollview Will be able to understand the contentsize it should use.

You can find more detailed info here
http://infinite-edward.tumblr.com/post/66865604683/uiscrollview-contentsize-and-autolayout-gotcha

Comment: The key is to explicitly set the content size of the scrollview. Thank you!